# Bootstrap 3 Changing font-size Affecting radio and checkbox Lining with Text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Bootstrap 3 by default has font-size:14, but I need to set it to font-size:12 px.
In this case radio buttons are not lined with text. How to fix this?

Even if I open getbootsrap documentation and change font-size to 12px radio buttons are not lined with text.

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1"> 1
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2"> 2
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox3" value="option3"> 3
</label>


body {
    font-size: 12px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ynGg/

[image]

Comment: Hi. I think the answers below are not practical; maybe we changed line-height to another value. A practical solution may be setting margin of radio and checkboxes with respect to font size and line height attributes. I have thought it but couldn't realize how to achieve that. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Adjusting the line-height works fine for me.

```
.checkbox-inline, .checkbox {
   line-height: 1.9;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ynGg/3/

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution:

```
// Position radios and checkboxes more better
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
    margin-top: ((@line-height-base - 1)/2) * 1em;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
}
```

This solution is not only care about font-size, also line-height. Working examples:

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.25">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.125em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.25
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.25">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.125em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.25
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.25">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.125em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.25
</label>
</div>

<hr/>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.428571429">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.21em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.428571429
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.428571429">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.21em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.428571429
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.428571429">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.21em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.428571429
</label>
</div>

<hr/>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.6">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.3em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 12px; line-height: 1.6
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.3em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 14px; line-height: 1.6
</label>
</div>

<div>
<label class="radio-inline" style="font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.6">
 <input style="margin-top: 0.3em; width: 1em; height: 1em;"
  type="radio"
  value="Deneme"/>
  font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.6
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.checkbox-inline, .checkbox {
  line-height: 1.9;
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to your code.